# OpenCV - real time object recognition (3d) rotation invariant

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I need to recognize a certain type of object within a frame captured by a camera. I have used in the past haar classifiers, but I need something more "flexible". Imagine having to detect a car "object" regardless of its angle of rotation (X,Y,Z) and illumination. In this case the (2D) captured shape of the object can vary much depending on the angle of rotation. I saw that OpenCV implements different algorithms for this task (SVM/SURF/SIFT/HOG/BOF/...), but what is the most suitable?

The requirements are as follows:

- must be fast (realtime)
- 3d rotation invariant
- illumination invariant
- scale invariant
- color invariant
- I have to get the object position (bounding box)

Comment: Have you tried Template Matching? http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

Comment: I believe this is a research-level problem in computer vision. If you find a solution, let me know.

Comment: @MarkMiller i have not found the solution yet